# A regexp to retrieve either og:url meta or link rel="canonical"

Tags: php, regex, scrape, canonical-link

i'm trying to write a script to scrape canonical URL from a remote URL. 
I'm not a professional developper, so if something is ugly in my code, any explanation would (and will) be appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is either look for:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-canonical-url.com/is-here-and-look-no-dynamic-parameters-186.html" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.another-canonical-url.com/is-here" />`
```

... and extract the URL out of it.

My code so far :

```
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = strtolower($content);
    $content = preg_replace("'<style[^>]*>.*</style>'siU",'',$content);  // strip js
    $content = preg_replace("'<script[^>]*>.*</script>'siU",'',$content); // strip css
    $split = explode("\n",$content); // Separate each line

    foreach ($split as $k => $v) // For each line
    {
        if (strpos(' '.$v,'<meta') || strpos(' '.$v,'<link')) // If contains a <meta or <link
        {
        // Check with regex and if found, return what I need (the URL)
        }
    }
    return $split_content;
```

I've been fighting with regex for hours, trying to figure out how to do so, but it seems it's well above my knowledge.

would someone know how I need to define this rule ?
Plus, does my script seems okay to you, or is there room for improvement ?

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: You can't just do a strpos search for `og:url` or `rel="canonical"`?

Comment: You're using regex in `preg_replace` and check for final results with `strpos`... you should go with `preg_match_all`! and the better way is using a DOM parser.

Comment: ... damn you're right, I should look for og:url or rel="canonical" instead of meta or link. I feel stupid now. Thanks, I wouldn't have think of that by myself.

Comment: @revo, sorry, too technical for me, i didn't catch what you meant. For the DOM part, are you suggesting xpath, rather than a regex approach ?

Comment: It's not so complicated. DOMDocument will do the job as well.

Comment: I'm sure it's not complicated, i just don't know how to use preg_match_all in that situation / or DomDocument for that matter. Would you care to elaborate a little ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument` this is how you can get the property and content

```
$html = '<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-canonical-url.com/is-here-and-look-no-dynamic-parameters-186.html" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$attr = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if ($meta->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($meta->attributes as $attribute) {
            $attr[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($attr);
```

Output ::

```
Array
(
    [property] => og:url
    [content] => http://www.my-canonical-url.com/is-here-and-look-no-dynamic-parameters-186.html
)
```

The same you can get for the 2nd URL as

```
$html = '<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.another-canonical-url.com/is-here" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$attr = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('link') as $link) {
    if ($link->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($link->attributes as $attribute) {
            $attr[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}


print_r($attr);
```

Output ::

```
Array
(
    [rel] => canonical
    [href] => http://www.another-canonical-url.com/is-here
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Learned my lesson, next time, go with DOMDocument rather than regex for that kind of job.

Comment: Yes for parsing the html in PHP DOMDocument is the best solution since regex cant do all and at times it becomes too complicated to write those regex for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), simply load your HTML into the DOMDocument object and use getElementsByTagName and then loop the results until one of them has the right attributes. As if you were writing Javascript.

Comment: I'm looking at a DOMDocument example right now, and yes, it seems appropriate to what i'm trying to do. Thanks for the suggestion, i'll try and do it that way. I'll be answering my question if i make it work.